# How to make a random super increasing array

Tags: java, arrays, random, knapsack-problem

I'm having a lab about making a Merkle Hellman Knapsack,the request said i need to make an automatically super increasing array but i don't know how to make it,is there any way to make it ? Thanks for reading

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] wInt = random.ints(8, 1, 999).toArray();
for(int i = 0; i < 8 - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < wInt.length; j++) {
        if(wInt[i] > wInt[j]) {
            int temp = wInt[i];
            wInt[i] = wInt[j];
            wInt[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `random.ints(...).sorted().toArray()`? Not sure what an "automatically super increasing array" is, but it looks like you're trying to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

A [superincreasing sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superincreasing_sequence) is one where each term is at least as big as the sum of all the preceding terms. Therefore, one way to generate a superincreasing sequence would be to keep track of the sum of all elements currently in the sequence, then to add some random, nonzero number onto the total when forming the next element. In pseudocode:

```
sequence = []
total = 0
while the sequence has fewer than n items in it:
    total += some random number
    append total to the sequence
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to translate this into your Programming Language of Choice.